# What should go to HtmlHelper, to own new helper, or to view engine extension?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

this is more like a design, best practices question, and partly separation of concerns question. I hope you can help me to decide (and to saturate my obsession for good design). The question is basically about what should go to HtmlHelper, own helper (e.g., MyFancyHelper), and what shoud go to view engine extension?

We use APS.NET MVC5 / Razor, and for some cases we use HtmlHelper extensions, own helpers, and WebViewPage constructs. As of now, text-only output goes to view engine extension, e.g. our localization is done this way:

```
public abstract class WebViewPage<TModel> : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>
{
    private ILocalizationService _localizationService;

    public override void InitHelpers()
    {
        base.InitHelpers();

        _localizationService = (ILocalizationService)System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof(ILocalizationService));
    }

    public string LS(string key, params string[] parameters)
    {
        return _localizationService.GetStringOrDefault(key, parameters);
    }
}
```

So in cshtml, we can use just `@LS("Domain.Subdomain.Text")`.

We use HtmlHelper for for short and repetitive pieces of HTML code, such as custom checkboxes: `@Html.CustomCheckbox()`.

Basically, the rule of thumb is - if the product is raw text, based on some parameter(s), it goes to view engine extension (WebViewPage), if the product is HTML snippet, it goes to HtmlHelper. But - what about something in between - e.g.,

```
<meta name="description" content="@???" />
```

It doesn't feel right either in HtmlHelper (it simply isn't html code), I also think it doesn't even belong to view engine extension (it's too specific) - and to create own helper (e.g. MetaHelper) seems like an overkill for two - three methods. I've seen several instances of this:

```
<meta name="description" content="@(Html.MetaDescription())" />
```

but it feels wrong, the output isn't html markup.

The question is - do you think that what I've just described makes sense, and what would you do in such case - would you create several specific helpers, would you keep even these methods in HtmlHelper, you'd create different specialized helpers, or would you do something else?